# FBA Providers, .NET Roles, .NET Users, missing in IIS if App Pool is in v2.0 version

Tags: asp.net, iis, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, fba

I am migrating a WSS 3.0 database to a new SharePoint 2010 farm. It is a FBA Web Application and when I go to configure the Providers, `.NET Roles and Users` are missing. If I change the Web Application app pool to v4.0, this options appear. If it stays in v2.0, the options are gone. It need to stay in v2.0 since this is SharePoint related.

I am doing this operation in a Windows Server 2012, SQL Server 2014 and IIS 6.2

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed nothing. IIS 8 and above are .NET 4 based so that you will no longer be able to change settings for .NET 2 in IIS Manager, but the settings can still be changed by manually editing the related config files.